# targeting only same page anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, hashchange

From a web analyst perspective on any given website i am looking find out which same page anchors are clicked the most by console logging the anchor's text value (inner html text) in the console for now.

The approach i took was to take the current page url after every anchor click and check to see if their had been any hash changes at the end of the url string and if so print that anchor's text value in the console.

```
var anchor = $("a[href^=\\#]");

anchor.on("click", function(){
    if("onhashchange" in window) {
        var anchorText = this.text;
        console.log(anchorText);
}
});
```

I'm having issues with the code I wrote because its returning the inner Html text for any anchors on the page(except the ones with external links) but I only want to track the ones that lead to a section on the same page.

Would the approach i took need to be revised to even begin with ?

Here is some of the html I am working with and different anchors I want to track and ones I don't.

```
 <!-- Where the click on the anchor i want to target happens  -->
  <nav>
   <h2 class="wb-inv">Promotions</h2>
     <ul class="toc lst-spcd col-md-12">
       <li class="col-md-4">
         <a href="#story1" class="list-group-item">Anchor for section 1</a>
       </li>
    </nav>

 <!-- below is the section of the same page the anchors would point to -->
  <div class="col-md-12 pull-left">
    <h2 id="story1">Section 1 Title </h2>
      <p>Random paragraph 1</p> 
   </div>

 <!-- The html I'm working with contains a set of tabs that reveal information as you click them, the href attribute and the id are both in the anchor. This is an example of anchors I wouldn't want to track-->
  <a tabindex="-1" id="details-panel1-lnk" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="details-panel1" href="#details-panel1">
   <h2 class="h5 mrgn-tp-sm mrgn-bttm-sm">Online</h2>
  </a>
```

Comment: `if ('onhashchange' in window)` doesn't check if the event occurred, that just checks if the browser supports that type of event.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors that navigates to element on page is logged.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var anchor = $("a[href^=\\#]");
   var url = $(window);

   anchor.on("click", function(e){
     if ( $('#' + $(this).text()).length ) {
          console.log($(this).text());
     }
   });
})
```

```css
.section {
   height: 400px;
}
.section:nth-child(even) {
   background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="one">
 <a href="#one">one</a>
</div>
<div class="section" id="two">
 <a href="#two">two</a>
</div>
<div class="section" id="three">
 <a href="#three">three</a>
</div>
<div class="section" id="four">
 <a href="#four">four</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking to only get the inner html text on the anchor clicked. My main issue is that i want to only filter for anchors that navigate to an area of the same page, at the moment its capturing text for any anchor regardless of it fits that criteria or not.

Comment: Is it that you only want to track the clicks that lead to a specific area of the page?  Rather than the same page in general?

Comment: yeah so within a given page, only track clicks on anchors that jump to a any area of the same page and I would ignore any other anchors that do otherwise.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the html you are working with?  It would help to understand the structure you are working with.  I updated my answer with a snippet that checks for an existing element based on the id of the anchor that was clicked.

Comment: thank you for your help ! With the websites i was working with i had some recurring issues with a "share this page" button. I had to include .not() object to omit it from the rest of the anchors i wanted to target. i ended fixing my code and came out with the solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchor = $("a[href^=\\#]").not("a[href=#shr-pg0]");

   anchor.on("click", function(){
      var anchorText = this.text;
      $(window).one("hashchange",function() {
        console.log(anchorText);
     });
  });
```